# NoSuchElementException thrown eventhough webdriver found and clicked the element

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

An intended element was found and clicked by selenium wedriver (eclipse java), yet the test failed with a `NoSuchElementException` thrown. After the click, the expected page displayed correctly, so why would the test fail? Why is this exception being thrown? Anyone experienced this anomaly anytime earlier?

Comment: Have you tried printing the stack trace to identify the line that's causing the issue? Also please paste a snippet of the code so we can identify what, if anything, needs to be done to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes bit longer time to load html page due to which selenium does not find the elements and it throws `NoSuchElementException`. Try puting main thread to sleep for 5-10 ms and check if it works.

Comment: You probably meant 5-10 sec? 5-10 ms definitely will not help

Comment: @Khuzi, the element was definitely found withing the stipulated time because the expected page launched successfully; yet the test fails

Answer (score 0):

Use Explicit wait,it helps to wait upto visible element .
Example:
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
    element.click;

```
Hope it will  works.
```